# Change on naval distances

Tags: oceanography

I am working on a shipping company and we have several applications to calculate the distance between two ports. My curiosity was triggered by the fact that, time by time I see a small change on the distance. For example, when the distance was 2000 miles it changed to 2003 miles.

I searched if there was any infrastructure changes on the port but my search came back negative.

How could this addition on miles be explained?

Comment: Does your software calculate the shortest distance independent of weather, sea state, and shipping route regulations - such as [Traffic Separation Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_Separation_Scheme)?

Comment: @daniel.neumann The software I am using is Netpas. As far as I understand it does not use any of the above. Only shipping route regulations should be used but why a route could be altered?

Comment: It might be due to changes in the marine spatial planning in the coastal waters (wind turbine farms, military restricted areas, environmental protection areas, for other reasons *blocked* areas). Or are there maybe tides included in the routing software?

Comment: According to the Netpas webpage it provides "*distance data with (S)ECA, Weather Forecast, Piracy Alert and many other powerful functions*". It sounds reasonable that you get slightly varying distances.

Comment: @daniel.neumann Weather is not yet integrated, and SECA and piracy are parameters that remain constant to me.

Comment: Are the map projections the same? Would tides come into play?

Comment: If TSSs are included, is it possible that the 2000nm was in one direction and the 2003 in the other? Using the other lane approaching a port could easily add a few miles.

Comment: @Inkenbrandt I am afraid I do not have any information about projections and tides are not considerate into the calculations.

Comment: @Flyto I believe the same as you, but I cannot find any working example. Because whatever I have tried they return the same result regardless direction.

Comment: Could be a setting to follow either great circle or thumb line (constant heading), which would be a bit longer.